# Sum if person is in the same row of number

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table with numbers in column A. Columns B to D are filled with names (Person X, Person Y, etc), that don't repeat themselves within the same row:

```
A       B     C      D
----------------------
100  |  X     Z      B
80   |  Y     X      K
60   |  Z     A      Y
```

I want to use something like a SUMIF to sum all the numbers for the names I have. For example, for X we'd get 100+80=180, and for Y 80+60=140.

Comment: Where do you want that formula to be? It doesn't seem like it is possible to tack it on to your existing data, but would have to be in an entirely separate and independent place, right?

Comment: Exactly, I would have the name in, for example, column F and the respective sum in column G. Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=SUMPRODUCT($A$1:$A$3*($B$1:$D$3="X"))
```

You can replace `"X"` with any cell reference. The formula exploits the stated fact that X, Y etc *"don't repeat themselves within the same row"*

You could also use full columns to avoid setting the row numbers... but it will be a little slower:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A:A*(B:D="X"))
```

Comment: Worked like a charm :) Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

**Approach 1:**
If you have just three columns `B:D`, use 3 `SUMIFs` like below, (Where `column F` is your sum criteria)

```
=SUMIF(B:B,F1,A:A)+SUMIF(C:C,F1,A:A)+SUMIF(D:D,F1,A:A)
```

[image]

**Approach 2:**
If there are more columns, use the below formula in `column E` - helper column,

```
=B1&C1&D1
```

This formula concatenates the columns to a single string. Then enter the formula to get the sum like below in `column H`,

```
=SUMIF(E:E,"*"&G1&"*",A:A)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create hashmap. While traversing if name already exist then add value to it otherwise create a new entry with that name and add value.